# 'String' is not a sub type of type map<String, dynamic> flutter error

Tags: flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, dart-null-safety

//Hello, I am trying to pass Map as an argument to the new screen but it ends in error with a red screen. here is my code first the class where the Map is defined, I am using firebase for a database with this app.
I am trying to make get job app so the employer post the job(i use textformfield) but when I try to received data as a map it show error

```
class FloatSearchBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const FloatSearchBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  FloatSearchBarState createState() => FloatSearchBarState();
}
class FloatSearchBarState extends State<FloatSearchBar> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  Map<String, dynamic>? userMap;
  late FloatingSearchBarController controller;
  static const historyLength = 4;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = FloatingSearchBarController();
    filteredSearchHistory = filterSearchTerms(filter: null);
  }

 isLoading = true;
    });
    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await _firestore
        .collection("PostJob")
        .where("jobType", isEqualTo: selectedTerm.toLowerCase())
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userMap = value.docs[0].data();
        isLoading = false;
      });
      print(userMap);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => searchresultPage(
                  recevieduserMap: userMap!['jobType'], key: UniqueKey())));
    });
  }
...
```

*and now the class which is getting pushed:-

```
...class searchresultPage extends StatelessWidget {
  FloatSearchBar yes = new FloatSearchBar();
  Map<String, dynamic> recevieduserMap ;
  searchresultPage({required this.recevieduserMap,Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              top: 70,
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Card(
                              elevation: 15,
                              child: Container(
                                width: double.infinity,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2)),
                                    Text('Job Type:- ' + recevieduserMap["jobType"],style: GoogleFonts.breeSerif(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,wordSpacing: 1),),),
                                    Text('Job Descreption:- '+recevieduserMap["jobDescrebtion"],style: GoogleFonts.breeSerif(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,wordSpacing: 1),),),
                                    Text('Company Location:- '+recevieduserMap["companyLocation"],style: GoogleFonts.breeSerif(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,wordSpacing: 1),),),
                                    Text('Company Name:- '+recevieduserMap["companyName"],style: GoogleFonts.breeSerif(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,wordSpacing: 1),),),
                                    Text('\$${recevieduserMap["payrate"]}'.toString(),style: GoogleFonts.breeSerif(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,wordSpacing: 1),)),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
...
```

Comment: userMap is a Map<String, dynamic>, but what about userMap!['jobType'], are you sure that is not a String? can you post an example of how your Firestore document scheme looks like?

Comment: What about `searchresultPage(recevieduserMap: userMap!, key: UniqueKey())`?

Comment: i tried the above method but still it have a red screen error saying type 'null' is not a sb type of string

Comment: On the firebase i use data as a string type